# What SQL query is the equivalent to this function for retrieving a list of unique items

Tags: sql, android-room

I'm trying to change this function into an SQL query (using Room). The goal is to return a list of items with no duplicates.

A duplicate is defined by either the `item.id` or any combination of `linked ids` being present.

```
fun removeDuplicates(items: List<Table>?) : List<Table>?{
    val returnItems = ArrayList<Table>()

    items?.distinctBy { _item ->
        _item.id
    }?.forEach { item ->
        val LID1 = item.linked_id_1
        val LID2 = item.linked_id_2

        val isFoundReturnItem = returnItems.firstOrNull {
                    (it.linked_id_1 == LID2 && it.linked_id_2 == LID1) ||
                    (it.linked_id_1 == LID1 && it.linked_id_2 == LID2)
        }

        //only add to our new list if not already present
        if(isFoundReturnItem == null)
            returnItems.add(item)
    }

    return returnItems
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question right here is the answer for Microsoft SQL. Structure:

```
Select Distinct Field1, Field2, ...
From Table
Where Field1 between 'a' and 'm'
```

Your Script: The distinct command makes distinct rows.

```
Select Distinct Item
From YourTableName
```

You can also use GROUP BY this allows aggregations on distinct values

```
Select Field1, Field2 = max(Field2), ...
From Table
Where Field1 between 'a' and 'm'
Group by Field1
```

Comment: I never use this syntax (`Field2 = max(Field2)`) for an alias, i use `max(Field2) as Field2`, but this works too 

Comment: I like to keep all the names of the fields on the left, so my list is easy to read. That's what I love about SQL, so many ways to do the same thing 